# Finding and replacing words with asterisks, in a text file output

Tags: haskell

Hello I am new at Haskell and i'm having problems trying to get this script to work. 
This script reads in arguements from a command line and find them in a seperate text file.

E.G: cat.txt | ./redact  house big cat (in compiler)

It redacts certain words in a text file by replacing them with stars (****)asterisks. 
The number of stars used for each redacted word should equal the
number of characters in the word.

```
module Main where

import System
import Data.Char
import Data.List

lowercase :: String -> String
lowercase = map toLower

main = do 
arg1 <- getArgs
txt <- getContents
putStr (redact txt arg1)

redact :: String ->[String] -> String
redact input xWords = unlines [ work line | line <- lines input ]
where work line = unwords [ foo word | word <- words line ]
      foo w | lowercase(w) == lowercase(xWords) = convertWord w 1
        | otherwise                         = w

convertWord :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
convertWord :: map (const '*')
```

However, when i try to compile this, GHCi returns the error: "redact.hs:21:27: parse error on input " ' ". 
So the code:

```
convertWord :: map (const '*')
```

is causing the problem.

And finaly when I enter: (cat.txt | ./redact  house big cat) in the compiler I get the error: "interactive:1:14: parse error on input '|' " 
So I would also like a solution for this error.

Info:
Windows 7
GHCi Compiler, Version 7.0.4

Answer (score 2):

```
convertWord :: map (const '*')
```

should be

```
convertWord = map (const '*')
```

Use `::` to provide a type annotation. Use `=` to define a function or variable.

Meanwhile, this

```
cat.txt | ./redact house big cat
```

looks like it should be this

```
type cat.txt | redact house big cat
```

and entered directly at the dos prompt (command prompt), *not* in ghci. (I am assuming that the file you wish to process is called `cat.txt`.)

(You are using Windows, but the tutorial you are using seems to assume you are using a Mac or Linux.)

Answer (score 1):

```
convertWord :: map (const '*')
```

The `::` operator is used to declare something to have a given type. So the above line is saying "`convertWord` has the type `map (const '*')`", which obviously doesn't make any sense. You probably wanted a `=` there.

```
cat.txt | ./redact house big cat
```

I don't know who told you to write that into GHCi, but that's not valid Haskell code. It's shell script - you need to type that into a (unix) shell.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to mention (other than that `::` should be `=`) is that the type signature you give for `convertWord` is wrong.

The signature you gave, `Eq a => [a] -> [a]` states that, for any type which supports equality, `convertWord` will turn a list of that type into another such list. So, a list of `Int`, say, would be turned into another list of `Int`. That can't be right because `'*'` is not an `Int`.

What should the signature be? Well, you obviously want to use it to turn a `String` into another `String`, so `String -> String` would definitely work for this example. The most general type for `convertWord`, however, is `[a] -> String` as you can find out by asking GHCi (enter `:t map (const '*')`) or by looking at the types of `map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]` and `const '*' :: a -> Char` and seeing how they match up.